# How to use DataMapper `NOT LIKE` clause?

Tags: ruby, database, orm, sinatra, datamapper

I'm using DataMapper in a Sinatra project.  I'd like to be able to use a `NOT LIKE` stament in a DataMapper finder method, but cannot figure out how to do so.

One might imagine that this would work:

`@people = People.all(:female => 1, :name.like.not => '%julie%')`

...but DataMapper throws an error.  Switching the order of `not` and `like` doesn't help.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [to the docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html) you can use subtraction to produce `NOT` queries:

```
# Subtraction produces a NOT query
Zoo.all(:state => 'IL') - Zoo.all(:tiger_count.gte => 5)
# in SQL => SELECT * FROM "zoos" WHERE 
#             ("state" = 'IL' AND NOT("tiger_count" >= 5))
```

Therefore the answer would seem to be:

```
@people = People.all(:female => 1) - People.all(:name.like => '%julie%')
```